# How to read Firebase Data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

This feels like a really dumb question, but I have spent 5 hours trying to understand the simplest possible concept of getting data out of my Firebase Realtime Database:

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
var players = [];

firebase.database().ref('roomid-1').on('value', function(snapshot){
    let blob = snapshot.val();
    players = blob.Players;
    console.log(players);
});

function Listing(){
    let group = players.map((player, index) =>
    <div className="col-4" key={index}>
        Player: {player.name} | {player.color}
    </div>
    );
    return group;
}
```

However,  Renders nothing, despite being able to see the data I want in the console log:

```
0: {color: "green", name: "Rod"}
1: {color: "red", name: "Todd"}
```

But I can't figure out how to get any of the data out of the ".on()" function. And I've tried any number of abstractions. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Updated with all the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "./../firebase";

let players = [];

firebase.database().ref('roomid-1').on('value', function(snapshot){
    let blob = snapshot.val();
    players = blob.Players;
    console.log(players);
});

function Listing(){
    let group = players.map((player, index) =>
    <div className="col-4" key={index}>
        Player: {player.name} | {player.color}
    </div>
    );
    return group;
}


export default function Players(props){
    
    return <div className="row">
        <Listing />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can't access any of the data in the app. "Listing" renders an empty group.

Comment: That is not due to firebase. It is because of how React works. Can you paste other code parts too?

Comment: I added in the entirety of the code for the component in question. It's worth noting that it renders correctly when I preload "Players" with the correct array, and I can make updates to the array elsewhere in the code and it works, but any updates done inside of the ".on()" function don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

React won't re-render when the variable `players` changes, because it's not part of any component state. I would suggest using the `useState`  hook in the `Players` component to create a variable `players` and a method to update its value `setPlayers`. Using the `useEffect` hook, you could make your api call and, when the data is returned from the api, call `setPlayers` to update the component state. then pass `players`  from the `Players` component state as a prop to the `Listing` component.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll give it a try.